# Convert to HTML / change formatting

Tags: html

I have a CSV file with a cells filled with text formatted like this.

```
&lt;p&gt;
   This is some sample text&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
   This is some sample text&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
   &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I need this to be converted to HTML tags. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, if you simply copy paste the whole text into a new notepad file and save it as sample.html and open this html file in a browser, you will see that it is already a html file.

Instead if you want to convert the < to < etc,  Open the csv file in either excel of notepad and use replace function. Do following replacements.

Replace `&lt;` with a `<`
Replace `&gt;` with a `>`

and save the csv file as a html file just by clicking save as in notepad and give a name as newsample.html or something. Now you can open in a browser like  any other html file.

Comment: allrighty ! thats it. problem solved. **Thanks** Buddha :-)